gcc .so binding fails on ubuntu 24 when built on ubuntu 22
I build a C++ program and a shared lib (mylib.so) on ubuntu.
If i build and run the program on ubuntu 22 (gcc 11.4.0) everything is fine.
If i try to run the same binaries on ubuntu 24 this fails to load mylib.so.
Inspection using LD_DEBUG reveals:
ldout.txt.12101:     12101: mylib.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: 
_TIFFwarningHandler (fatal)

_TIFFwarningHandler is a symbol from libtiff which is part of mylib.so and build there from full sources - no additional library. How can this even be treated as a external symbol?
If i now build the same program on ubuntu 24 (gcc 13.2.0) this works and runs as expected.
Its sufficient just to replace mylib.so - then the executable created on ubuntu 22 runs on ubuntu 24.
Can anybody explain this behavior?
How can i get the build from ubuntu 22 make running also on ubuntu 24?

You want to be able to answer the following questions. Is the offending symbol referenced from your program on Ubuntu 22? If so, which object (executable or .so) references it, and which object provides it? Note, these objects may or may not be yours (could be system libraries). Answer the same questions for Ubuntu 24. Helpful tools are ldd <file> and nm -D <file> | grep <symbol> .

The difference between the two .so files is:
ubuntu 22:
nm bin/mylib.so | grep -i _TIFFwarningHandler 
                 U _TIFFwarningHandler
0000000000253920 B _TIFFwarningHandlerExt

ubuntu 24:
nm bin/myLib.so | grep -i _TIFFwarningHandler 
000000000023f480 D _TIFFwarningHandler
000000000024b918 B _TIFFwarningHandlerExt

TIFFwarningHandler is undefined when built with ubuntu 22.
But its not when compiling with ubuntu 24.
But in ubuntu 22 this symbol is found in libtiff.so.5:
binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 [0]: normal symbol `_TIFFwarningHandlerExt' [LIBTIFF_4.0]

In ubuntu 22  libtiff.so.5 does no more exist - instead  libtiff.so.6 is used. and this does not export _TIFFwarningHandler
symbol=_TIFFwarningHandler;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.6 [0]
...
myLib.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _TIFFwarningHandler (fatal)

Problem was that the file /libtiff/src/tif_unix.c was not in the makefile.
So mylib.so had no instance of _TIFFwarningHandler  On Ubuntu 22 this symbol was found in libtiff.so.5. In Ubuntu 24 libtiff.so.6 no more contains this.
